# what is the best way to include more than one js file into wordpress theme ?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am trying to add many js files to my newly created theme (I am new to wordpress theming )
I was trying to do it in this way :

```
function includejQuery() {
    if (!is_admin()) {
        wp_deregister_script('jquery');
        $jqueryPath = get_bloginfo('template_directory') . '/js/jquery-1.6.2.min.js';
        wp_register_script('jquery', $jqueryPath);
        wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
   }
}
function includeddAccordionUI() {
    if (!is_admin()) {
        wp_deregister_script('ddaccordion');
         $ddaccordionPath = get_bloginfo('template_directory') . '/js/ddaccordionUI.js';
          wp_register_script('ddaccordion', $ddaccordionPath , array("jquery"));
          wp_enqueue_script('ddaccordion'); 
    }
}

add_action('init', 'includejQuery');
add_action('init', 'includeddAccordionUI');
```

the above mentioned idea work just fine to include one file but if you include 2 file php will go into infinite loop (or the page won't stop loading )

is there any better way to include many js files ?

Comment: can you eliminate the possibility that it is looping due to the .js files?

Comment: also, just try to put the second function's contents (within is_admin) into the first.

Comment: also, don't forget to use no conflict wrappers for jQuery in your second script. http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script#jQuery_noConflict_wrappers

Comment: @Ivan , I am not sure what is child theme , but i am starting form very simple wordpress theme and its doesn't have js

Comment: @Aram , the no conflict wrappers helped me , thanks its working now , feel free to move your answer down , so i can set it as correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the action `wp_enqueue_scripts`when enqueuing scripts front end. This way you don't have to check if you're in admin. Use `admin_enqueue_scripts` when you actually want to load it in admin. This is not only to get rid of your bug, but also to get rid of the conditional. Also use only one function and load all js from that function, to prevent possible duplication of code (such as your current conditional). Now if this does not work, it has nothing to do with Wordpress and probably is due to the js. A last recommendation is to use the included js files, the usually suffice!

Codex page for wp_enqueue_script: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script